# How to return multiple coulmns in a csv with correct format

Tags: python, csv, utf-8, export-to-excel, utf-16

It's my first time posting here, and I'm new to working with python in my job. I've googled and trouble shot this to my best ability.

Summary:
I'm trying to take a file of usernames and file names and rip out all of the non utf8 characters. In the list of 40k or so records for file name, there are a mix of utf8, utf16, and other language encodings.

Problem:
I can't get python to correctly format the csv with both username and non utf8 file name. I can't get it to make a new tab and line for each record and its corresponding user. My print statement works exactly how I need it to look- it's perfectly delimited from what I can see.  I just can't figure out out to write both columns to csv. I need the Sender_Email column to keep my primary key for some later joins.

## Here's what my source csv looks like:

```
sender_email, file_name
test@test.com, utf16filename.xlxs
tester@test.com, utf16filename.xlxs 
mrstest@test.com, utf8filename1.pptx 
mctestertester@test.com, utf8filename2.pdf
mrstest@test.com, utf8filename3.docx
mctesterson@test.com, utf8filename4.docx
mrstest@test.com, utf8filename5.docx
```

## Desired output: Rip all the non-utf8 or ascii characters out

```
sender_email, file_name
mrstest@test.com, utf8filename1.pptx 
mctestertester@test.com, utf8filename2.pdf
mrstest@test.com, utf8filename3.docx
mctesterson@test.com, utf8filename4.docx
mrstest@test.com, utf8filename5.docx
```

What I have so far- The print statement is exactly what I need and it works. All of my results in the file name output are utf8 when view them in Terminal from what I can see by spot checking. The code also works when I just write the file_names column without my Sender_Email column.  I can only get the csv to format correctly if I just write the file_name column, but then I lose my primary key (sender_email).

```
import csv
with open ('MixedUTF8andUTF16FileNamesAndSenderEmail.csv', 'r') as inFile:
readFile = csv.reader(inFile)
for row in readFile:
    try:
        sender_email = row[0]
        file_names = row[1].decode('ascii')
        print sender_email+'\t'+file_names
        with open('asciionlycharacters.csv', 'a') as finalFile:
            finalFile.writerows(sender_email+'\t'+file_names)
    except:
        pass
```

## what the exact csv looks like when I open it in excel

```
sender_email  file_name 
utf8filename1.pptx 
utf8filename2.pdf 
utf8filename3.docx 
mctestertester@test.comutf8filename4.docx
mrstest@test.comutf8filename5.docx
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line

```
finalFile.writerows(sender_email+'\t'+file_names)
```

doesn't do what you think it does. You are using it to write one line to your file, but `writerows()` expects a list of lines. Try this instead:

```
finalFile.write(sender_email+'\t'+file_names+'\n')
```

You're making life hard for yourself by doing `try...except...pass`. That can mask all sorts of problems you would really like to know about. The exception you want to catch is in the line

```
file_names = row[1].decode('ascii')
```

so put the `try...except` around that.

```
try:
    file_names = row[1].decode('ascii')
except UnicodeDecodeError:
    continue
```

Comment: This worked! I feel kinda dumb, because looking at this it was obvious. Thank you for the suggestion on the except. I redid my run and it did catch somethings. Thank for all your help!

Comment: I apologize. Thank you for your help!